# Prevent a Unix domain socket file in the filesystem from being deleted while socket is bound

Tags: linux, macos, unix, unix-socket

Is it possible on Linux or MacOSX to prevent a Unix domain socket file (e.g. in /tmp) that is currently bound from being deleted? I want a mode 0777 socket that users can connect to but that users cannot delete while the daemon is running.

Right now a normal user can 'rm' the socket, preventing anyone else from accessing it until the daemon is restarted. Seems like it should be 'busy' if it's bound.

Comment: You might get more elegant solutions on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). Migration would be a shame though, because I think this of genuine interest for (server) programming - if it's a matter of 'securing' the unix socket from malicious clients though appropriate POSIX/BSD system calls, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a new subdirectory and set read only permissions on the directory after you make the socket:

```
mkdir /tmp/blah
cd /tmp/blah
# do stuff to create /tmp/blah/socket
chmod 555 /tmp/blah


rm /tmp/blah/socket

rm: cannot remove /tmp/blah/socket: Permission denied
```

(or the equivalent to that from C / your language of choice)

Comment: Looks like this might be the only portable solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on the directory that contains the socket. `/tmp` is somewhat special in that it has the "sticky bit" set on the directory (if you execute `ls -ld /tmp` you will see the permissions field is usually: `drwxrwxrwt` or, more usefully, mode 1777. That sticky bit (the `t` at the end) is important when set on a directory. Quoting `man chmod`:

> The  restricted  deletion  flag or sticky bit is a single bit, whose interpretation depends on the file type.  For directories, it prevents
> unprivileged users from removing or renaming a file in the directory unless they own the file or the directory;  this  is  called  the  re‐
> stricted  deletion  flag for the directory, and is commonly found on world-writable directories like /tmp.  For regular files on some older
> systems, the bit saves the program's text image on the swap device so it will load more quickly when run; this is called the sticky bit.

This is exactly what you want - file-system level protection against a user removing the file. It is also 100% portable to all modern UNIX-like environments.

So, if you are creating your endpoint in `/tmp` you already have the protections you want. If you want to create the endpoint elsewhere, for example `/opt/sockets`, simply `chmod 1777 /opt/sockets`. The last part of the "trick" to getting the protections you want is to ensure that the `root` user is the actual owner of the endpoint. If the endpoint is owned by user `fred` then `fred` will always be able to delete the endpoint, which may well be a desirable thing. But if not, simply `chown root:root /path/to/endpoint`.